# Microsoft NLB clustered web server not fetching web page

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, web-server, iis-7, windows-server-2012-r2

I have just set up 2 web servers running IIS 7, I have clustered them using Microsoft NLB. Both host IPs are added to the cluster and both hosts converged without fail.

However, when I tried to browse the webpage using the NLB address, it still return with no response from the server. My understanding is that by hitting up the NLB address I should be able to get the NLB to fetch the webpage as the host IP is binned to the IIS. I am able to get the webpage to fetch via the host IP without problem.

Brief structure of my cluster:

[image]

Action taken:

- I have set the cluster manager to listen to the ports that the web server would be using: TCP 80, 81, 443.
- I attempted to telnet the ports, but it returned with connection failed.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Have you taken a look at these gotchas with NLB? http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/12/09/balancing-act-what-you-really-ought-to-know-about-windows-server-nlb.aspx